# Where is my memory being consumed?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, top, htop

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 server which is reporting relatively low free RAM:

```
top - 11:28:31 up 5 days, 20:12,  3 users,  load average: 0.18, 0.26, 0.27
Tasks: 268 total,   1 running, 267 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.1 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7786.5 total,    506.1 free,   1329.4 used,   5951.1 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   4096.0 total,   3965.5 free,    130.5 used.   6020.5 avail Mem

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 373096 root      20   0    8200   3996   3316 R   1.0   0.1   0:01.04 top
    872 mysql     20   0 2843736 480140  15652 S   0.7   6.0  87:22.66 mysqld
    563 root      rt   0  280136  17940   8200 S   0.3   0.2   1:37.67 multipathd
    745 syslog    20   0  224320   4812   3396 S   0.3   0.1   1:28.21 rsyslogd
      1 root      20   0  169488  10424   6264 S   0.0   0.1   1:44.98 systemd
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.12 kthreadd
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp
      6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-events_highpri
      9 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq
     10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:03.55 ksoftirqd/0
```

The server has 8GB of physical RAM and only 1.3GB free.  The rest seems to be tied up in the buffer/cache.  However, a list of running processes show that the highest consumer is the mysql daemon which is using only 6% of total RAM.

Is there a way to report the true memory consumption and how can I free up the buffer/cache?

Comment: Ah ok, so "-/+ buffers/cache: is shown, because it shows how much memory is free when ignoring caches; caches will be freed automatically if memory gets scarce"  - I've technically got a lot more physical RAM available then

Comment: shortly said you havd 7g installed nearly 6gb available, so only one has been used